# Перебор всех чекбоксов в цикле

Tags: php, циклы

Здравствуйте.

Такой вопрос: подскажите, как реализовать перебор нескольких чекбоксов на странице в цикле.
Должно получиться что-то вроде:
если чекбокс чекнут, то выполнять действие и проверить так каждый чекбокс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое удобное будет через jquery:

```
var sList = "";
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    var sThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
    sList += (sList=="" ? sThisVal : "," + sThisVal);
});
console.log (sList);
```

pps; хм) не посмотрел, что для пхп
тут есть маленькая проблема, в пхп никак не передать тип поля, передается только имя и значение, поэтому есть такой вариант:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 3">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 4">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 5">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
            echo $check; //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
                         //so, if I were to check 1, 3, and 5 it would echo value 1, value 3, value 5.
                         //in your case, it would echo whatever $row['Report ID'] is equivalent to.
    }
}
?>
```

Как вы видите, имена у checkbox'ов одинаковые, с маленьким исключением, к имени добавлены квадратные скобки [], что позволяет в пхп передать эти чекбоксы как массив. ну и настороне пхп обрабатывать их как массив ;)

Comment: очень круто, спасибо.